# Can we call surjective and injective onto and into?

Tags: functions

How often is terminology introduced or changed in the math community? I know that John Conway did it all the time - but he was distinguished and often naming as-yet-unnamed species.

I would like to see a minor change in terminology: Injective and surjective functions are usually referred to as 'one-to-one' and 'onto' respectively. But this sometimes leads to confusion with bijective functions. Indeed, Wikipedia notes, "The term one-to-one correspondence must not be confused with one-to-one function."  Since 'one-to-one' and 'onto' are, in a way, complements of each other, why not change them to 'into' and 'onto'?

Surjective => 'onto'

Injective  => 'into'

Any reason not to? Thoughts?

Comment: $f$ can be a map from $A$ into $B$ without being injective.

Comment: You can call them Humpty and Dumpty, respectfully, if you want to.  But what ever you use, you must ensure your readers understand how you define them.  Why not just stick with injective and surjective?